# Showing A Widget Inside Google Assistant Via Custom Intent

Tags: google-assistant, app-actions

I want to show a widget in Google Assistant. After searching through all the BIIs, I found there isn't one for my use case. Is this a thing that is possible, or do I have to go through a BII?

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/widgets#how_assistant_displays_widgets) states that it is possible through a "custom intent configured for widget fulfillment" but they don't explain how to do that.

I tried creating a capability with a custom intent like so:

```xml
    <capability android:name="custom.actions.intent.SOMETHING">
        <app-widget
            android:identifier="SOMETHING_WIDGET"
            android:targetClass="com.example.Widget"
            android:targetPackage="com.example">

            <extra
                android:name="hasTts"
                android:value="true" />
        </app-widget>

        <intent
            android:identifier="SOMETHING_FALLBACK"
            android:targetClass="com.example.FallbackActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.example" />
    </capability>
```

And I created this shortcut:

```xml
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="SOMETHING_SHORTCUT"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/ShortcutShortLabel">
        <capability-binding android:key="custom.actions.intent.SOMETHING" />
    </shortcut>
```

Now here is the problem. If I do it this way (static shortcut) it doesn't even appear either on the launcher nor the GA shortcuts page.

On the dynamic shortcut route, I also tried to do what was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75890990/2832835), deep linking to GA directly. This works but for my account only. No other user can get the shortcut to appear on the GA shortcuts list.

If I add the following dependency as the documentation suggests:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.core:core-google-shortcuts:1.1.0")
```

Attempting to invoke the dynamic shortcut after that dependency is added results in Google Assistant trying to load shortly before cancelling out with the following message in logcat:

```
Unsupported client op: ui.SHOW_APP_WIDGET. Ignoring.
Successfully executed ui.SHOW_APP_WIDGET. Status: IGNORE
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!